# VBA - How to Insert empty columns in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel spreadsheet in which I am generating two columns L and M using VBA code. After generating two columns with data in it, I wanted to insert two new empty columns to the left of Column L. How can I do it?

As shown in the image, I want to add new empty columns to the left of L. So that the current Column L and Column M should be moved to Column N and Column O respectively.

My code is as follows-

```
Sub Wave()

 Dim N As Integer
 Dim Inp As Integer
 Dim Op As Integer
 Dim Src As Integer
 Dim MAX As Integer

 MAX = 1502
 Src = 0
 N = 0

 Op = ActiveSheet.Range("K2")
 For Src = 0 To MAX Step 1
   Inp = ActiveSheet.Range("K" & 2 + Src)
   Op = ma0 * Inp + ma1 * mx1 + ma2 * mx2 - mb1 * my1 - mb2 * my2
   mx2 = mx1
   mx1 = Inp
   my2 = my1
   my1 = Op

   ActiveSheet.Range("L" & 2 + Src) = Op
   ActiveSheet.Range("M" & 2 + Src) = ActiveSheet.Range("L" & 2 + Src) - ActiveSheet.Range("K" & 2 + Src)

 Next

End Sub
```

[image: Image1]

Comment: simple suggestion for you, try macro recording ...

Comment: Record a macro that inserts a column, and then look at the code it generates. This should be the first thing you do when trying to write Excel VBA code - see if you can get Excel to do the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
ActiveSheet.Columns("L:M").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

You should disable CutCopyMode so that you don't inadvertently insert

Sub InsertRowAbove()
'
' InsertRow Macro
' Pushes active row down
'
    Dim N As Long

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False 'This line to get rid of clipboard.

ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
N = Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
Range("G4").Copy Range("G5:G" & N)
Range("J4").Copy Range("J5:J" & N)
```

End Sub